# Reemplazar un valor en una matriz por infinito - Python

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

Deseo reemplazar el valor "0" por "infinito" en una matriz

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import math

matriz = np.array([5,0,0,6]).reshape(2,2)

#cambiar los valores de 0 por infinito
matriz[matriz == 0 ] = math.inf
print(matriz)
```

El error que me sale es:
**OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer**

¿comó puedo solucionar mi error?

Comment: Debes añadir el parámetro que especifique tipo float al crear el array. Es decir `np.array([5,0,0,6], dtype=float)`

Comment: Me sirvió, Gracias